# What enemies did the company intend to use Xenomorphs on?

Tags: alien-franchise

I find using xenomorphs as weapons problematic -- if the company was interested in xenomorphs for biomedical applications or materials science, I would have found that more plausible.

But given that they wanted to use them as weapons, do we know enough, from books, etc. about the Alien universe to know what enemies the company intended to loose the xenomorphs on?

Is it against humans? On Earth or in colonies? Or could there be an extraterrestrial enemy that a new sort of weapon was needed against?

Comment: I've edited to make it clearer what the question is, I hope that's helpful?

Comment: I think it was more that the company wanted to develop more weapons based on the xenomorphs and sell to the military for megabucks.

Comment: They were intended to sell them to the highest bidder

Comment: @Valorum: but who would want them and for what conflict and how would they be used? I could see them as getting out of hand as unlikely as that might seem to others.

Comment: @releseabe There are probably lots of terrorist organizations that would like to have a weapon that can be stored as an egg, and that could wipe out a country, or the planet in a matter of weeks. "Give us what we want or we all die screaming" is useful in a negotiation.

Comment: As @HorusKol mentioned, they probably weren't looking to sell aliens for direct use; rather figure out how a living creature could be that lethal and durable, and use the insights to make better weapons.

Comment: Predators......

Comment: @BjornEriksson: why would weyland deal with terrorists when it no doubt has governments as customers?

Comment: @releseabe I doubt a government would be as interested. A government would lose its power and its people if the xenomorphs overrun its planet. That makes their threats of releasing them appear hollow. A group of fanatics on the other hand would have no such qualms.

Comment: Obviously they'd be for use against other militarized policorps, like Maas Biolabs or Coherent Light.

Comment: @releseabe Why sell to only one side when you can sell to both?

Comment: I'm strongly against this - but of you assume ALIEN is on the blade runner universe there are still wars between colonies.  If you assume Jurassic park universe...the military has weaponized velociraptors so xenomorps are clearly the next generation weapon.